# How can I find the ratio of a medium triangle to a smaller triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, ratio

[image]

I know area is $\frac{1}{2} bh$ but I can't use that since there are no numbers. The triangles are isosceles and the medium triangle and the small triangle share a side. How can I find the ratio of the areas?

Comment: In the picture, below the triangle there is a $1$.

Comment: But since the question asks about ratio of areas, the measurement that @RodrigoPizarro has pointed out doesn’t matter.

Comment: Anyways, that isn't the point of my comment. The OP said that "I can't use that since there are no numbers", which in this case is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$\frac{S_{\Delta DGO}}{S_{\Delta DLO}}=\frac{GO}{OL}=x$$ and $OL=a$.

Thus, $$DL=DO=GO=ax,$$ $$DG=GL=ax+a=a(x+1)$$ and since $$\Delta DOL\sim\Delta GDL,$$ we obtain:
$$\frac{DL}{GL}=\frac{OL}{DL}$$ or
$$\frac{ax}{a(x+1)}=\frac{a}{ax}$$ or
$$x^2=x+1,$$ which gives
$$x=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}.$$